# Python - Descriptor - Broken class

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, python-descriptors

I follow the tutorial out of the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#complete-practical-example) and an example by [fluent Python](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/fluent-python/9781491946237/). In the book they teach me how to avoid the `AttributeError` by get, (e.g., when you do `z = Testing.x`) and I wanted to do something simliar with the set method. But it seems like, it lead to a broken class with no error.

To be more specific about the issue:

1. With outcommented line `Testing.x = 1` it invoke the `__set__` methods.
2. With uncommented line `#Testing.x = 1` it does **not** invoke the `__set__` methods.

Can someone teach me why it behaves this way?

```
import abc

class Descriptor:
    def __init__(self):
        cls = self.__class__
        self.storage_name = cls.__name__

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        else:
            return getattr(instance, self.storage_name)

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        print(instance,self.storage_name)
        setattr(instance, self.storage_name, value)

class Validator(Descriptor):

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        value = self.validate(instance, value)
        super().__set__(instance, value)

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def validate(self, instance, value):
        """return validated value or raise ValueError"""

class NonNegative(Validator):
    
    def validate(self, instance, value):
        if value <= 0:
            raise ValueError(f'{value!r} must be > 0')
        return value

class Testing:
    x = NonNegative()
    def __init__(self,number):
        self.x = number

#Testing.x = 1
t = Testing(1)
t.x = 1
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? When you do `Testing.x = 1`, you replace the descriptor with an integer, so why are you doing that in the first place?

Comment: *Why* is to prevent users from handling the package in bad manner.

Comment: @a_guest the question is why is the `__set__` method never been called to prevent that.

Comment: My question was rather why you would replace the *descriptor itself*, which is what `Testing.x = 1` does. If this was for testing purposes, to check if the users of your library can somehow bypass the checks, well, yes they can. But why would they?

Comment: @a_guest Your question isnt related to mine. I had a unexpected behavior and a desired functionality. The meaning of any action isnt in my intrest, nor am I able to fully understand the human nature. As AKX pointed out, the *lookup chain* was the missing information for me to understand why my expected behavior was wrong indeed.

Comment: The point is, you didn't describe the "desired functionality" as part of your question. So it wasn't clear what exactly you were expecting (actually, it's still not clear). If your goal is to prevent `Testing.x` from being overwritten, then it seems your questions has not been answered yet. If you are wondering about the asymmetry between `__get__` and `__set__` when no instance is involved (i.e. `Testing.x` vs. `Testing.x = ...`), then again it seems that this has not been answered. But since you marked the answer below as accepted, it seems that you actually asked for something else.

Comment: @a_guest *If you are wondering about the asymmetry between __get__ and __set__ when no instance is involved (i.e. Testing.x vs. Testing.x = ...), then again it seems that this has not been answered* now you are confusing me again. Why does the *lookup chain* and of course the different functionality of `__get__` and `__set__` does not explain this behavior?

Comment: @a_guest Yes I do want *to prevent Testing.x from being overwritten* and yes I wonder about *asymmetry between __get__ and __set__*. But I think it is cleared by the *lookup chain* and the immanent functionality of __get__ and __set__. I thought I would do `Testing.x.__set__(value)` but I was doing `Testing.__dict__['x']`

Comment: Well, you could ask two questions; first, why does `Testing.x` even invoke `__get__` with `None` as the `instance` and not just return the descriptor object directly? And second, since for `Testing.x`, the descriptor gets invoked as `__get__(None, Testing)`, why isn't the same true for `Testing.x = ...` (i.e. `__set__(None, ...)`)? The answer is, the first behavior is needed for implementing e.g. [classmethod](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#class-methods), and for the second, controlling attributes is not done by the object, but by its class (or metaclass).

Comment: You can't truly prevent `Testing.x` from being overwritten, even if you controlled attribute access via `__setattr__` defined on a custom metaclass, a user could still do `type.__setattr__(Testing, 'x', ...)` and overwrite that class attribute. But as an author of your library, you don't really have to care, if a user goes that far, they probably know what they are doing anyway.

Comment: @a_guest would you mind writing an answer with a little bit more details? I'm fully confused now and I dont feel able to put these information togather at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attribute access is generally handled by [`object.__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) and `type.__getattribute__` (for instances of `type`, i.e. classes). When an attribute lookup of the form `a.x` involves a descriptor as `x`, then various [binding rules](https://docs.python.org/3.10/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors) come into effect, based on what `x` is:

1. *Instance binding:* If binding to an object instance, `a.x` is transformed into the call: `type(a).__dict__['x'].__get__(a, type(a))`.
2. *Class binding:* If binding to a class, `A.x` is transformed into the call: `A.__dict__['x'].__get__(None, A)`.
3. *Super binding:* [...]

For the scope of this question, only (2) is relevant. Here, `Testing.x` invokes the descriptor via `__get__(None, Testing)`. Now one might ask why this is done instead of simply returning the descriptor object itself (as if it was any other object, say an `int`). This behavior is useful to implement the [classmethod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) decorator. The descriptor HowTo guide provides an [example implementation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#class-methods):

```py
class ClassMethod:
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f

    def __get__(self, obj, cls=None):
        print(f'{obj = }, {cls = }')
        return self.f.__get__(cls, cls)  # simplified version


class Test:
    @ClassMethod
    def func(cls, x):
        pass


Test().func(2)  # call from instance
Test.func(1)  # this requires binding without any instance
```

We can observe that for the second case `Test.func(1)` there is no instance involved, but the `ClassMethod` descriptor can still bind to the `cls`.

Given that `__get__` is used for both, instance and class binding, one might ask why this isn't the case for `__set__`. Specifically, for `x.y = z`, if `y` is a data descriptor, why doesn't it invoke `y.__set__(None, z)`? I guess the reason is that there is no good use case for that and it unnecessarily complicates the descriptor API. What would the descriptor do with that information anyway? Typically, managing how attributes are set is done by the class (or metaclass for types), via [`object.__setattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__) or `type.__setattr__`.

So to prevent `Testing.x` from being replaced by a user, you could use a custom metaclass:

```py
class ProtectDataDescriptors(type):
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if hasattr(getattr(self, name, None), '__set__'):
            raise AttributeError(f'Cannot override data descriptor {name!r}')
        super().__setattr__(name, value)


class Testing(metaclass=ProtectDataDescriptors):
    x = NonNegative()

    def __init__(self, number):
        self.x = number


Testing.x = 1  # now this raises AttributeError
```

However, this is not an absolute guarantee as users can still use `type.__setattr__` directly to override that attribute:

```py
type.__setattr__(Testing, 'x', 1)  # this will bypass ProtectDataDescriptors.__setattr__
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort and time to help me a better understanding of what's going on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
Testing.x = 1
```

replaces the descriptor you've set as a class attribute for `Testing` with an integer.

Since the descriptor is no more, `self.x = ...` or `t.x = ...` is just an assignment that doesn't involve a descriptor.

---

As an aside, surely you've noticed there is no true `x` attribute anymore with your descriptor, and you can't use more than one instance of the same descriptor without conflicts?

```
class Testing:
    x = NonNegative()
    y = NonNegative()

    def __init__(self, number):
        self.x = number


t = Testing(2345)
t.x = 1234
t.y = 5678
print(vars(t))
```

prints out

```
{'NonNegative': 5678}
```

Comment: I didnt catch up at the moment. I've learned that python recognizes a descriptor object by either `__set__`, `__get__` or `__del__` and I thought about that the attribute gets overwritten before. But it confuses me that the `__set__` method isnt called once to prevent that. To have multiple descriptors there is an index but I deleted it for this question.

Comment: You may wish to (re-)read the [docs section on descriptor invocation](https://docs.python.org/3.10/reference/datamodel.html#descriptor-invocation).

Comment: oh, its because of the *lookup chain*. Now I got it thank you.

Comment: no. it is because you are making an assignment to the _class_ and not an instance of `Testing`. Descriptors are invoked from the class for reading (`Testing.x` will invoke your. `__get__`), but for writting, the attribute on the class is changed directly - it only uses `__set__` when you operate on an instance of the class ( `t` in your snippet)

Comment: Sorry for "taking away" your points. But the newly accepted answer put a lot of effort into this question.